# How can I override this gradient filter using CSS?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to get rid of/override the gradient filter over images on my homepage, and I'm using [this child theme](http://my.studiopress.com/themes/altitude/#demo-full)

I'm new to this, but this is the code I've been editing:

```
.image-section {
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2)), color-stop(30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 30%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 80%,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#33000000', endColorstr='#e6000000',GradientType=0 );
display: table;
overflow: hidden;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried changing it to:

```
.image-section {
background: none;
background-color: transparent;
display: table;
overflow: hidden;
table-layout: fixed;
width: 100%;
}
```

I've even tried "!important", but nothing seems to fix it. Could this php (in customize.php) have something to do with it?

```
global $wp_customize;

$images = apply_filters( 'altitude_images', array( '1', '3', '5', '7' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the page. There reason you cant override the background is because its using a media query: `@media all {}`.

As suggested by the mighty @BoltClock the media does not add specificity so for a more or less quick fix:

### css

```
div .image-section {
    background: none;
}
```

will add specificity so if the last rule does not work there is probably some javascript or php that is applying the class after the css is applied.

Comment: `@media all` is equivalent to having no media statement specified at all. Even if the media query was restrictive in some way, media queries have no effect on specificity. Also what you have is invalid since there is no selector.

Comment: @BoltClock sutch mean comment... Forgot the .image-section will edit it. 

All mighty BoltClock whats the reason her css is does not overwrite the gradiant background?

Comment: Why do people consistently mistake directness and correcting someone as being rude?

Comment: @J.Steen because there is a difference between: "This is wrong" and "I think you maybe forgot this"

Comment: @Persijn Yes. One is direct. The other is needlessly sugarcoaty and in my eyes rather sarcastic.

Comment: @J.Steen we are humans not machines. No one talk the same to there mother and there boss.

Comment: @Persijn This place is about information, facts, the questions and the answer. It's not about us as human beings feeling fluffy.

Comment: @J.Steen This place is about helping other; with facts, and information. Doing mistakes is what makes us human.

Comment: @Persijn Yes, and BoltClock corrected your mistake, which led to a better post by you.

Comment: @J.Steen but how is it helping? He's just pointing out what's wrong, not how to improve it. And that's why I think of it as mean.